# How to pass the resultBundle from loginActivity (when authorizing the user) back to AccountManager callback

Tags: android, oauth, accountmanager

I have an problem in my implementation of AbstractAccountAuthenticator in Android.
At first please let me know if I getting it right how it should work..
When I somewhere in my app call the getAuthToken method for particular Account and AuthTokenType, Android tries to find that token in system keychain. If it is there, it simply calls callback a puts the token into the provided Bundle.
If there is no such token (and only in that case), it instantiates my own implementation of AbstractAccountAuthenticator and calls the getAuthToken method from there?

That is how I am getting that..

Below is my implementation of the getAuthToken method in my Authenticator

```
@Override
public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account,
                           String authTokenType, Bundle loginOptions) throws NetworkErrorException {
    Log.v(TAG, "getAuthToken()");


    if (!authTokenType.equals(AuthenticatorConfig.AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE)) {
        final Bundle result = new Bundle();
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE, "invalid authTokenType");
        return result;
    }
    final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
    return bundle;
}
```

In LoginActivity I have a WebView where I load the OAuth login form, let the user fill in their credentials and authorize the app. 
After I got the token I subsequently call this code

```
KosAccount.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addAccount(getUserDataResponse);
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            final Bundle result = new Bundle();
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE,    AuthenticatorConfig.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authToken);

           //Here I need to put the result into the intent as an extra?

            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
```

As you can see I am adding new account to account (that needs to be refactored and done only if there is no such account, otherwise I only need to update current account)

Finally there is my main problem..I dont know how to pass the result bundle back to the AccountManager....I should to put there as an extra to the resultIntent? This whole thing seems to be poorly documented and it took to me quite a lot of time to get here:)

**Currently when I try to get the token from the AccountManagerFuture provided in my AuccountManagerCallback i got a NullpointerException, the token is not there..**

PLease could you help me how to provide the token back there, or just tell me how to implement this better?